# TLS Record layer: Security Parameters

Tags: tls

In TLS RFC, Security Parameters in Record Layer are defined

```
      BulkCipherAlgorithm    bulk_cipher_algorithm;
      CipherType             cipher_type;
      uint8                  enc_key_length;
      uint8                  block_length;
      uint8                  fixed_iv_length;
      uint8                  record_iv_length;
      MACAlgorithm           mac_algorithm;
      uint8                  mac_length;
      uint8                  mac_key_length;
      CompressionMethod      compression_algorithm;
      opaque                 master_secret[48];
      opaque                 client_random[32];
      opaque                 server_random[32];
```

master_secret, clinetrandom ..etc are exchanged in handshakeprotocol

But cipherAlgorithm, mac algorithm?

These are exchanged in handshakeprotocol too?

I read RFC but I couldnt find about it

When these values(about encryption and mac ) are exchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cipher an mac algorithms are defined by the cipher suite which gets negotiated during the TLS handshake. The client offers a list of supported cipher suites in the ClientHello and the server accepts a specific one inside the ServerHello. See also [section 8 of RFC 5246 (TLS 1.2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-64):

> 8. Cryptographic Computations
>    ...  The authentication, encryption, and MAC algorithms are determined by the cipher_suite selected by the  server and revealed in the ServerHello message.

In [Appendix C of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-83) you then find some mappings of cipher suite to cipher and mac algorithms:

```
Cipher Suite                            Key        Cipher         Mac
                                        Exchange

TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL                 NULL         NULL         NULL
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5                   RSA          NULL         MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA                   RSA          NULL         SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256                RSA          NULL         SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                RSA          RC4_128      MD5
...
```